# How to use LocationMatch wildcard in Require directive?

Tags: regex, apache, authentication

I'm serving up Git via HTTP and want to lock down access to each repository using Active Directory groups.  The current relevant configuration follows:

Here's the top-level directive in the Apache config:

```
<LocationMatch "^/git/.*$">
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all

    AuthLDAPBindDN "someaccount@domain.local"
    AuthLDAPBindPassword "somepassword"
    AuthType Basic
    AuthBasicProvider ldap
    AuthLDAPURL "ldap://dc.domain.local:3268/DC=domain,DC=local?sAMAccountName?sub?(objectClass=*)" NONE
    Require ldap-group cn=Domain Users,cn=Users,dc=domain,dc=local
</LocationMatch>
```

Then separately I have something like this for each repository:

```
<Location /git/somerepo.git>
  <Limit GET PUT POST DELETE PROPPATCH MKCOL COPY MOVE LOCK UNLOCK>
    Require ldap-filter memberof:1.2.840.113556.1.4.1941:=CN=somerepo,OU=Git,DC=domain,DC=local
  </Limit>
</Location>
```

This works but requires changes to the configuration whenever a repository is added/removed.  Is there a way to extract the value matched by the `.*` in the `LocationMatch` so we can just insert it into the `require ldap-filter` directive?

Answer (score 0):

Looks like this isn't possible as written since `LocationMatch` doesn't support backreferencing.

Source: https://serverfault.com/a/423913/28470